# vue3 defineProps value is not passed to the child

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuejs3

I want to make reusable chart components.

The data is passed to the child in props, but the chart is not displayed. I don’t' know the reason.

parent component code

```
<ColumnChart :title="'Parent Title'" :name="degree" :data='data'/>
```

data value

```
[
{name: 1, y: -5},
{name: 2, y: -5},
{name: 3, y: -5},
{name: 4, y: 1},
{name: 5, y: 3},
]
```

child component code

```
<script setup>
import {reactive, ref} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
    data: Array,
})
let seriesData = reactive({
    credits: false,
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    },
    accessibility: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: props.title,
        align: 'center'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%H:%M}'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: props.name,
        data: props.data
    }]
})
const chart = ref()
</script>
<template>
    <highcharts ref="chart" :style="{ height: '100%'}" :options="seriesData"></highcharts>
</template>
```

result page

Title in String is passed to the child, but data in Array is not displayed on the page.
[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWjo2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWjo2.png)]

The result is the same for computed.

Comment: How do you get that data in parent component?

Comment: It's unlikely that the example looks like it's shown, otherwise it would work. If this data is expected to change, don't use it once, do this either in a computed or watcher

Comment: I guess it's because of proxy objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your "series" key of "seriesData"  is trying to access props.name, that does not exist.

Try using computed instead of reactive for seriesData creation.

```
let seriesData = computed({ ... })
```

Comment: I have used computed, but Array data is not output.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the "props.data" at some point?
If it is printed to console, means the props is passed to the child.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this to options api and solved it.
highcharts-vue does not support composition api.